# Failed to find code-generated model provider - AWS Amplify

Tags: android, aws-amplify

I'm getting the below error:

> Failed to find a code-generated model provider.

AWS amplify code which throwing this error:

```
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSApiPlugin());
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSDataStorePlugin());
Amplify.configure(context);
```

I am following the below tutorials:

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/generate-model/q/integration/android
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/overview

I have tried generating models and models get generated successfully but still while running the app I am getting above exception.

Answer (score 1):

When you [generate models](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/android#code-generation-amplify-cli), you should expect to find various code-generated files in your application project. One of them will be `app/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/datastore/generated/model/AmplifyModelProvider.java`.

When you *build* your app, Android Studio will compile that java file into a class file, and include it into your binary.

At *runtime*, on the phone, the `AWSDataStorePlugin()` constructor will attempt to find that same `AmplifyModelProvider` by means of *reflection*.

I would verify that:

1. You do actually have the code-generated `AmplifyModelProvider`;
2. It is being built successfully;
3. It is **not** being stripped out by ProGuard/R8 minification.

If you're still not able to get it working, just use the one-argument version of the `AWSDataStorePlugin(...)` constructor, instead. That version allows you to explicitly specify the model provider, and does not use runtime reflection.

```kotlin
Amplify.addPlugin(AWSDataStorePlugin(AmplifyModelProvider.getInstance()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource needs to be updated:

Try running modelGen, then amplifyPush tasks:

| Category | Resource name | Operation | Provider plugin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Api | amplifyDatasource | Update | awscloudformation |

[image]